# \newenvironment where all text is typewriter (like \texttt)

Tags: fonts, macros, environments, typewriter

I'd like to have an environment that encloses all its content into the typewriter font as `\texttt{}` does. However, I do not want to use `\texttt{}` but an own environment, e.g. `\begin{allintypewriter}` because my text contains multiple paragraphs.

So instead of

```
\texttt{
My multiparagraph text
}
```

I'd like to write

```
\begin{allintypewriter}
My multiparagraph text
\end{allintypewriter}
```

Sorry, it's a newbe question, but how do I define a `\newenvironment` for this? (I do not want to use something like `\verbatim` because the text to be set as typewriter should contain other latex commands; only the font should be changed to typewriter for this environment)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The more general version of you question is dealt with here:

[How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/2693)

But since you only need to change the font family and not the font itself, your particular instance of it is much simpler:

```
\newenvironment{allintypewriter}{\ttfamily}{\par}
```