# How to define an "align" environment with typewriter font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, align

I tried to use the commands defined here: [Can I change all math output to use monospaced text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62978/can-i-change-all-math-output-to-use-monospaced-text) to change the font in the math environment. However, the following code does not compile:

```
\everymath{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
\everydisplay{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
    \begin{align*}
        T = \{
              \alpha : A \subseteq B,\\
               \beta : B \subseteq C\\
            \}
    \end{align*}
```

It compiles correctly in normal math mode (without using "align" and line breaks), or without the commands to change the font. How can I modify the font used inside the align environment to typewriter? (Similar to: [\newenvironment where all text is typewriter (like \texttt)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128875/newenvironment-where-all-text-is-typewriter-like-texttt) , but in math mode)

I would like to write something like:

```
    \begin{ttalign*}
        T = \{
              \alpha : A \subseteq B,\\
               \beta : B \subseteq C\\
            \}
    \end{ttalign*}
```

where the environment "ttalign" behaves likes "align", but with the typewriter font instead of the normal font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you looked into the [mathastext](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathastext?lang=en) package?

Comment: I looked into it after reading your comment. However, I did not understand how to use it to define a new environment. I edited my post to better describe what I want. Could you please elaborate more on how to use mathastext to achieve the align+typewriter effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reset `\tmp` every time: when you use `\mathtt` once, the relative math group is allocated and will no longer change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{ttmath}
 {\everymath{\ttmathgroup}\everydisplay{\ttmathgroup}}
 {}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  $\mathtt{\xdef\ttmathgroup{\fam\the\fam\relax}}$%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
T = \{
      &\alpha : A \subseteq B,\\
      &\beta : B \subseteq C\\
    \}
\end{align*}

\begin{ttmath}
\begin{align*}
T = \{
      &\alpha : A \subseteq B,\\
      &\beta : B \subseteq C\\
    \}
\end{align*}
\end{ttmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can define a `ttalign*` environment, if you prefer:

```
\newenvironment{ttalign*}
 {\everymath{\ttmathgroup}\everydisplay{\ttmathgroup}\csname align*\endcsname}
 {\endalign}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I was already using xparse, I defined a new environment this way:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ttmath}{}{\begingroup\everymath{\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}}{\endgroup}
```

And then, combined with the original align environment:

```
\begin{ttmath}
  \begin{align*}
        T = \{
            &\alpha : A \subseteq B,\\
            &\beta : B \subseteq C\\
        \}
    \end{align*}
\end{ttmath}
```